# How to apply partition by in lag function using postrgresql

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, psql, lag, partition-by

I have a table like as shown below

```
subject_id,    date_inside,             value
1           2110-02-12 19:41:00          1.3
1           2110-02-15 01:40:00          1.4
1           2110-02-15 02:40:00          1.5
2           2110-04-15 04:07:00          1.6
2           2110-04-15 08:00:00          1.7
2           2110-04-15 18:30:00          1.8
```

I would like to compute the `date difference between consecutive rows for each subject`

I tried the below

```
select a.subject_id,a.date_inside, a.value,
a. date_inside- lag(a. date_inside) over (order by a. date_inside) as difference
from table1 a
```

While the above works, I am not able to apply `partition by` for each subject. So, it ends up calculating the difference for all the rows (without considering the subject_id). Basically, the last row of each subject has to be `null` because that's his or her last row (and should not be subtracted from consecutive record of the next subject)

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
subject_id,    date_inside,             difference
1           2110-02-12 19:41:00          66 hours
1           2110-02-15 01:40:00          1 hour 
1           2110-02-15 02:40:00          NULL
2           2110-04-15 04:07:00          3 hours, 53 minutes 
2           2110-04-15 08:00:00          10 hours, 30 minutes
2           2110-04-15 18:30:00          NULL
```

Comment: You have not revealed all the details as your query refers to tables A and B

Comment: updated. It's only one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `PARTITION BY` clause, and also your expected output seems to want `LEAD`, not `LAG`:

```sql
SELECT subject_id, date_inside, value,
       LEAD(date_inside) OVER (PARTITION BY subject_id ORDER BY date_inside)
           - date_inside AS difference
FROM table1
ORDER BY
    subject_id,
    date_inside;
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of "partition by" to be simiar to how you could use "group by". In this case the logical boundaries are determined by subject_id so just include as part of the over clause:

```
select a.subject_id,a.date_inside, a.value,
a.date_inside - lag(a.date_inside) over (partition by a.subject_id order by a.date_inside) as difference
from table1
```